# In Android, when swipe to change the screen how to show an animation with both screen

Tags: android, android-animation

Sorry the title isn't clear enough. I don't know how to express it, but the image here says it all.

In the Google Reader App, if the uses swipe left or right on the current post, they will see the first post moves out as the second one moves in. It's a nice effect, but I have no clue how to implement it.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a ViewPager with fragments:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#a4c639"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>





 public class ReadRawActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewPager awesomePager;
    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 3;
    private static Context cxt;
    private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cxt = ReadRawActivity.this;

    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
}

private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{




            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
            }

        /**
         * Create the page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
         * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
         * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
         * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
         *
         * @param container The containing View in which the page will be shown.
         * @param position The page position to be instantiated.
         * @return Returns an Object representing the new page.  This does not
         * need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.
         */
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(cxt);
                    tv.setText("View Pager" + position);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.setTextSize(30);

                    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(tv,0);

                    return tv;
            }

        /**
         * Remove a page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
         * for removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
         * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
         *
         * @param container The containing View from which the page will be removed.
         * @param position The page position to be removed.
         * @param object The same object that was returned by
         * {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
         */
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((TextView) view);
            }



            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                    return view==((TextView)object);
            }


        /**
         * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed.  At this
         * point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been added or
         * removed from the container as appropriate.
         * @param container The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
         * page views.
         */
            @Override
            public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


            @Override
            public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

            @Override
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}

}


}
```